# I have updated my android studio to 3.0.1, then got this error, I'm badly stuck, Gradle file is not syncing

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio

You can see the error and file opened when try to gradle sync. I applied lot of solutions but useless.

[image]

Comment: have you updated your SDK

Comment: clean up and make your all support library to use the same version.

Comment: update compileSDKVersion and buildToolsVersion